# Хитрость с изображением в html

Tags: html, css, изображения

Есть у меня фото котика.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне нужно, чтобы при наведении на него мышью фото как бы приближалось, при этом сохраняя старые размеры. То есть, было оно скажем 700 на 500, так 700 на 500 и осталось, изменилось именно внутреннее содержание. Есть какое нибудь решение?
Вот так должно получится(не получилось сохранить размер как надо, но по сути надо при наведении фото обрезать и растянуть до размеров старого, еще и плавно это сделать)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

```css
.container {
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.wrapper {
 width: 300px;
 height: 150px;
 overflow: hidden;
 margin: 10px;
}

img {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 object-fit: cover;
 transition: transform 0.2s;
}

img:hover {
 transform: scale(1.5);
}

.top img { transform-origin: top; }
.right img { transform-origin: right; }
.bottom img { transform-origin: bottom; }
.left img { transform-origin: left; }

.collapse { transition: transform 0.2s; }
.collapse:hover { transform: scale(0.9); }
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="wrapper">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQpbZ.jpg" alt="">
 </div>
 <div class="wrapper top">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQpbZ.jpg" alt="">
 </div>
 <div class="wrapper right">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQpbZ.jpg" alt="">
 </div>
 <div class="wrapper bottom">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQpbZ.jpg" alt="">
 </div>
 <div class="wrapper left">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQpbZ.jpg" alt="">
 </div>
 
 <div class="wrapper collapse">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQpbZ.jpg" alt="">
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Чтооооо, это какая то черная магия. Спасибо

Comment: @Eternalblue добавил побольше вариаций

Comment: Вы просто волшебник